# Is my subclassing Common Controls tooltip destroying itself in WM_DESTROY before I can?

Tags: c, winapi, tooltip, comctl32

The program below creates a window with a Common Controls tooltip that subclasses the window. When I get a `WM_DESTROY`, I instinctively decide to destroy the tooltip, since [`WM_DESTROY` comes before child (and I assume owned as well) windows are destroyed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/26/443384.aspx), but `DestroyWindow()` fails, returning last error 1400 (`ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE`). (On wine, it returns 5 (`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`) instead. I'm assuming this is a bug with wine either setting the last error incorrectly or not at all; I can file one later.)

I have tested on Windows XP 32-bit andWindows 7 64-bit, with both Common Controls 5 and 6 (a command line "flag" is used below), and wine on Ubuntu 14.10 and 15.04 beta.

If the tooltip is destroying itself, what can I do to handle it? Should I just rely on that behavior? Or should I subclass the tooltip and handle `WM_DESTROY` myself? (Will two windows subclassing each other cause problems?)

Thanks.

```
// 31 march-2 april 2015
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS
#define CINTERFACE
// get Windows version right; right now Windows XP
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0501       /* according to Microsoft's winperf.h */
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0600            /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x05010000    /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void die(char *why)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error %s: %I32u\n", why, GetLastError());
    abort();
}

HWND tooltip = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CREATESTRUCT *cs = (CREATESTRUCT *) lParam;
    TOOLINFOW ti;

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        tooltip = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
            TOOLTIPS_CLASSW, L"",
            WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX,
            0, 0,
            0, 0,
            hwnd, NULL, cs->hInstance, NULL);
        if (tooltip == NULL)
            die("creating tooltip");


        ZeroMemory(&ti, sizeof (TOOLINFOW));
        ti.cbSize = TTTOOLINFOW_V2_SIZE;
        ti.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS | TTF_TRANSPARENT;
        ti.hwnd = hwnd;
        ti.uId = (UINT_PTR) hwnd;
        ti.hinst = cs->hInstance;
        ti.lpszText = L"this is a tooltip! wow!";
        if (SendMessageW(tooltip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) (&ti)) == FALSE)
            die("setting up tooltip");

        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (DestroyWindow(tooltip) == 0)
            die("deleting tooltips");
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void initCommonControls(BOOL);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BOOL comctl5;
    WNDCLASSW wc;
    HWND mainwin;
    MSG msg;

    comctl5 = FALSE;
    if (argc > 1)
        comctl5 = strcmp(argv[1], "comctl5") == 0;
    initCommonControls(comctl5);

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mainwin";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (RegisterClassW(&wc) == 0)
        die("registering main window class");

    mainwin = CreateWindowExW(0,
        L"mainwin", L"Main Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if (mainwin == NULL)
        die("creating main window");

    ShowWindow(mainwin, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(mainwin);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

// MSDN doesn't list a constant that only includes tooltips but says this and a few others do
#define wantedICCClasses (ICC_BAR_CLASSES)

static ULONG_PTR comctlManifestCookie;
static HMODULE comctl32;

// note that this is an 8-bit character string we're writing; see the encoding clause
static const char manifest[] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<assembly xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1\" manifestVersion=\"1.0\">\n<assemblyIdentity\n    version=\"1.0.0.0\"\n    processorArchitecture=\"*\"\n    name=\"CompanyName.ProductName.YourApplication\"\n    type=\"win32\"\n/>\n<description>Your application description here.</description>\n<dependency>\n    <dependentAssembly>\n        <assemblyIdentity\n            type=\"win32\"\n            name=\"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\"\n            version=\"6.0.0.0\"\n            processorArchitecture=\"*\"\n            publicKeyToken=\"6595b64144ccf1df\"\n            language=\"*\"\n        />\n    </dependentAssembly>\n</dependency>\n</assembly>\n";

void initCommonControls(BOOL comctl5)
{
    WCHAR temppath[MAX_PATH + 1];
    WCHAR filename[MAX_PATH + 1];
    HANDLE file;
    DWORD nExpected, nGot;
    ACTCTX actctx;
    HANDLE ac;
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc;
    FARPROC f;
    // this is listed as WINAPI in both Microsoft's and MinGW's headers, but not on MSDN for some reason
    BOOL (*WINAPI ficc)(const LPINITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);

    if (!comctl5) {
        if (GetTempPathW(MAX_PATH + 1, temppath) == 0)
            die("getting temporary path for writing manifest file");
        if (GetTempFileNameW(temppath, L"manifest", 0, filename) == 0)
            die("getting temporary filename for writing manifest file");
        file = CreateFileW(filename, GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,          // don't share while writing
            NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (file == NULL)
            die("creating manifest file");
        nExpected = (sizeof manifest / sizeof manifest[0]) - 1;     // - 1 to omit the terminating null character)
        if (WriteFile(file, manifest, nExpected, &nGot, NULL) == 0)
            die("writing manifest file");
        if (nGot != nExpected)
            die("short write to manifest file");
        if (CloseHandle(file) == 0)
            die("closing manifest file (this IS an error here because not doing so will prevent Windows from being able to use the manifest file in an activation context)");

        ZeroMemory(&actctx, sizeof (ACTCTX));
        actctx.cbSize = sizeof (ACTCTX);
        actctx.dwFlags = ACTCTX_FLAG_SET_PROCESS_DEFAULT;
        actctx.lpSource = filename;
        ac = CreateActCtx(&actctx);
        if (ac == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            die("creating activation context for synthesized manifest file");
        if (ActivateActCtx(ac, &comctlManifestCookie) == FALSE)
            die("activating activation context for synthesized manifest file");
    }

    ZeroMemory(&icc, sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX));
    icc.dwSize = sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icc.dwICC = wantedICCClasses;

    comctl32 = LoadLibraryW(L"comctl32.dll");
    if (comctl32 == NULL)
        die("loading comctl32.dll");
    f = GetProcAddress(comctl32, "InitCommonControlsEx");
    if (f == NULL)
        die("loading InitCommonControlsEx()");
    ficc = (BOOL (*WINAPI)(const LPINITCOMMONCONTROLSEX)) f;
    if ((*ficc)(&icc) == FALSE)
        die("initializing Common Controls (comctl32.dll)");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tooltip have not WS_CHILD style. all this kind of windows is full destroyed before owner windows receive WM_DESTROY. as result DestroyWindow(tooltip) and return error - ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE

Comment: Is this specific behavior of owned windows documented anywhere? MSDN doesn't say that owned windows are destroyed before I get the `WM_DESTROY`; all it says is "when the owner is destroyed"...

Comment: Is this specific behavior of owned windows documented anywhere? - dont know. empirical

Comment: @sutol thanks; I suppose I could try to reproduce those results myself as well...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know about the differences between parents/children and owners/owned; I know the tooltip has `WS_POPUP` so it's an owned window. I'm talking about those. Are you saying I'm reading the documentation wrong and that the documentation is really talking about parents and children window (and getting the terms wrong)? Because my question still stands in that case: does it talk about owners and owned windows at all?

Comment: when some window is destroyed, first is destroyed owned windows (without WS_CHILD style), than window is received WM_DESTROY, and than destroyed child windows (with WS_CHILD style). in this order. and this not only for tooltips. this is general rule

Comment: All right then, thanks. I still feel like this should have been explained somewhere (rather than us having to discover it for ourselves), but :S

Comment: really very rarely why is important this order. and not need to destroy any owned or child windows on WM_DESTROY event - this will be done auto by system. about child windows - direct say in docs - thay will be destroyed after WM_DESTROY. about owned - hard to say - is this documented (and same on all windows version), but really very rarely this is important

Comment: @andlabs: This is documented, albeit not explicitly. [Owned Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows): *"The system automatically destroys an owned window when its owner is destroyed. [...] After creating an owned window, an application cannot transfer ownership of the window to another window."* Destroying the owner window prior to the owned window would imply (temporarily) transferring ownership. Since this is not possible, there's only one way to skin this cat: Owned windows are destroyed prior to owners.